# Notice: Array to string conversion foreach

Tags: php, arrays, loops

After I use `var_dump($rows);` I get result from query as below:

```
object(stdClass)#11 (2) {
  ["id"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["name"]=>
  string(5) "riski"
}
```

but the result gives error

```
Notice: Array to string conversion
```

in this line :

```
foreach($rows as $val){
    $user .=  '<option value="'.trim(addslashes($val->id)).'">'.trim(addslashes($val->name)).'</option>';
}
```

How to convert the result to `foreach` result?

Comment: where from you are getting $rows? put the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please watch your array carefully. It is an associative array not a multidimenstional associateive array.

Try This:

```
$rows->id
```